# tell varnish not to cache requests ending in.html

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

1. How can I tell Varnish with the VCL configuration file not to cache
   any URLs ending in `.html`.  This is for a Magento website and I do
   not wish to cache any product pages which all end in .html.  I thought `?.html` or `*.html` might be the wild card I would need.
2. Also can I tell Varnish to treat any request for a url ending with
   the query string `?___from_store=0&___store=ie` the same as it would
   if the query string was not there.  So
   `example.com/?___from_store=0&___store=ie` would be treated the same
   as `example.com` by Varnish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wildcard I needed for part one of my questions seems to be `.*\.html$`

In my VCL I have

```
sub vcl_recv {
if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?(?:admin|api|.*.html$|cron\.php|checkout|checkout/cart|customer|advancednewsletter|onestepcheckout|onepage|hoi_turpentine|exporter|contacts|iphone|join|sitemap.xml)" ||
req.url ~ "\?.*__from_store=") {
return (pipe);
}
}
```

Comment: I would use .*\.html$ because else the second dot will match any character. Also are you sure you want to return "pipe" and not "pass"? See: https://www.varnish-software.com/book/4.0/chapters/VCL_Built_in_Subroutines.html#vcl-vcl-recv

Comment: @Ronald, thanks.  Pipe is being used as I'm using the [Magento_Turpentine](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine) extension which genrates the VCL, I simply added `.*\.html$` to their configuration section in the Magento admin panel, what's the difference between Pipe and Pass anyway?